# Express.js render simple html

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm making a web app which display a HTML table. The app is written in Express and is backed by mongo.

I need to dynamically style different boxes / cells in the table depending on a whole lot of different factors like data comparisons, data types and so on.

Right now, I'm trying to render the json I get from mongo using jade.

But what I need to do is to read the rows from mongo, apply table tags to the fields, basically construct a HTML table and echo it on the page AS-IT-IS.

Meaning, I'll be constructing html using the code and then display it as html, just like the rails html_safe method.

How can I do that with express.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use the `res.send()` method for this.

```
var table = '<table><tr><td>hi!</td></tr></table>';
res.send(table);
```

If you need to send it in multiple chunks to the browser, you can use nodes `res.write()` instead, as `res.send()` will end the response.

```
var table = '<table><tr><td>hi!</td></tr></table>';
res.write(table);
```